# IMemoryOwner with partially filled Memory buffer

Tags: c#, parsing, memory, buffer, memory-pool

I have a parser that takes an `IAsyncEnumerable<IMemoryOwner<char>>`. This allows it to enumerate over pages of buffered data. The reason the parser enumerates over `IMemoryOwner<char>` rather than `Memory<char>` is so that it can call `Dispose` on the `IMemoryOwner`, which will (I think!) release its internal `Memory<char>` back to the caller's `MemoryPool`.

So the caller of the parser utilises a method like this to create the `IAsyncEnumerable`:

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<IMemoryOwner<char>> GetPagesAsync(int bufferSize, StreamReader reader)
{
    int charactersRead;
    do
    {
        var bufferOwner = MemoryPool<char>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
        var buffer = bufferOwner.Memory;

        charactersRead = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer);

        yield return bufferOwner;
    } while (charactersRead > 0);
}
```

This is all fine until the final read when `charactersRead` might be less than `bufferSize`. Normally, I would just use `buffer.Slice(0, charactersRead)`, but I need to return the `IMemoryOwner` rather than the `Memory`. Is there a built-in way around this, or is it necessary to either implement your own `IMemoryPool` and `IMemoryOwner`, or create your own type to wrap both the sliced `Memory` and the `IMemoryOwner`?

Comment: [related runtime proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27869)

Comment: Also [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/70a1996fd390d8db5685ca0011d65cfb)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. I'll use your `SliceOwner` wrapper class and `IMemoryOwner` extension methods in your gist.